# Image in presenterImageView not displaying properly

Tags: cosmicmind

I modified the PresenterCard sample code to use my firebase database instead of the graph library. However, it does not display the images properly. Essentially the image is not scaling to fit the view. I have

```
presenterImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

how can I fix this?

EDIT:

I use the following code to download the image

```
storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
    let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
    if let image = pic {
        self.presenterImageView.frame.size.height = image.height
        Motion.async { [weak self, image = image] in
            self?.presenterImageView.image = image
        }
    }
}

card.frame.origin.x = 0
card.frame.origin.y = 0
card.frame.size.width = bounds.width

frame.size.height = card.bounds.height
presenterImageView.frame.size.height = 300
```

The image loads but it doesn't scale.

Comment: Can you share more of your setup?

Comment: @CosmicMind updated with more of my setup let me know if you need me to add more.

Comment: @CosmicMind have you had a chance to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem. Had to remove the line:

```
self.presenterImageView.frame.size.height = image.height
```

Works fine now!